# Probability weights for distance matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, distance, weighted

I am trying to calculate a distance matrix for all nominal variables using probabilistic weights, as suggested by Anderberg (1973: 124-5). Anderberg (1973: 124) argues that 'the desire to give rare classes extra weight appears frequently in the biological literature though systematic methods for assigning such weights are not offered. [...] Since rare events have low probabilities, the probability of an event is not a suitable weight; however any inverse function of the probability is potentially interesting.'

I will try to illustrate the situation using a simple and small data set in R.

```
var_1 <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A')
var_2 <- c('C', 'C', 'D', 'E')
var_3 <- c('G', 'G', 'G', 'F')
print(test.df <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3))
```

This produces the following dataframe

```
  var_1 var_2 var_3
1     A     C     G
2     A     C     G
3     B     D     G
4     A     E     F
```

We can calculate a distance matrix using Gower's coefficient as follows.

```
library(cluster)
test.dist <- daisy(test.df, metric="gower")
round(test.dist,2)
```

This produces the following matrix.

```
     1    2    3
2 0.00          
3 0.67 0.67     
4 0.67 0.67 1.00
```

We can see, for instance, that observations 1 and 2 are identical with respect to the three variables, resulting in a distance of 0. Observations 1 and 3 are not; they differ on two of three variables (`var_1` and `var_2`), resulting in a distance of 2/3=0.67.

Now my problem is the following. In the dataframe we can see that value `G` in `var_3` makes up for 75% of the data. I would like to use this information to adjust the contribution to similarity by this variable. In other words, because the probability of `G` in var_3 is three times higher than the probability of `F`, two observations (rows) containing `F` in this variable should be considered more similar than two observations containing the value `G`.

Just to provide some context: some of the variables in my real dataset have highly skewed distributions, with one value making up for 80% of all observations on that variable, and the 20% left is distributed over three other values.

(I do know I can add weights to the daisy function using the `weights` parameter, but these weights are not dependent on the distribution of the value of a feature, rather, these weights are constant for all values in the variable.)

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. You do not provide `test_corpus` and the R base function `dist` does not have a `metric=` argument or a `weights=` argument. Are you referring to the `daisy` function in package `cluster`?

Comment: I am sorry, you're right. `test_corpus` should have been `test.df`. I have changed that now. I have changed the `dist` function to `daisy` because of the `weights` parameter. I have tested the code and it should be reproducible now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that Anderberg's suggestion has not been implemented is probably an indicator of how difficult it would be to do so. The first problem is deciding how to set the weights. You base them on the relative frequency of the categories but that will change from sample to sample so you would be setting different weights for different samples. Secondly the Gower measure is already juggling multiple data types so you would be complicating it even more, but Gower is the only distance measure that attempts to combine different data types. The implementation does have a feature in the `cluster` package that may get close enough to what you want. Other implementations of Gower may have more features (search on gower distance r to get other packages implementing gower distance). In `daisy` there are two ways of handling binary data, symmetric and asymmetric. The difference is that '0-0's are counted in symmetric (aka simple matching coefficient), but not in asymmetric (aka Jaccard). Using asymmetric gets close to what you want, but you have to convert the factor variables to binary. The daisy function actually does this for categorical variables, but it does not let you specify asymmetric for variables that are not already binary.

```
A <- ifelse(test.df$var_1 == "A", 1, 0)
B <- ifelse(test.df$var_1 == "B", 1, 0)
C <- ifelse(test.df$var_2 == "C", 1, 0)
D <- ifelse(test.df$var_2 == "D", 1, 0)
E <- ifelse(test.df$var_2 == "E", 1, 0)
E <- ifelse(test.df$var_2 == "E", 1, 0)
F <- ifelse(test.df$var_3 == "F", 1, 0)
G <- ifelse(test.df$var_3 == "G", 1, 0)
dta <- cbind(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
```

There are ways to automate this process if you are going to use it, but this is a proof of concept answer. Your example data set is too small to show differences between the two approaches but if you boost your sample size in the example data, you should see differences.

```
daisy(dta, metric="gower")    # symmetric
daisy(dta, metric="gower", type=list(asymm=1:7))
```

Of course you could always write your own version of the Gower distance incorporating a custom weighting system. There are some generic distance functions available in R that let you write your own function to compute the distance between two rows and use that to compute a full distance matrix.

Comment: Thank you, dcarlson. I was indeed afraid Anderberg's suggestion wasn't implemented anywhere. I have written the function myself now, but it is, as expected, terribly slow -- partly due to inefficient coding, I think.

Your suggestion to look at converting the categorical variables to binary variables and using Jaccard's coefficient (asymm) had sprung to mind before, but I had made the mistake of not checking the data type of the variables, so the results were off. With your help, I hope I can do most of what I want. Thanks!

PS There is a typo in `type=list(assymm=1:7)` (assymm->asymm)